# Throwing error Layout is not defined. Even though present in R.java

Tags: android, android-layout, r.java-file

I have created a simple ListActivity and a custom List item called **`people_list_row.xml`** for the same ListView.
I am using a custom Array adqapter **`peopleCustomArrayAdapter.java`**. Inside this custom array adapter Eclipse is throwing the error **"people_list_row cannot be resolved or is not a field"**. Though layout **people_list_row** present inside `R.java`

There are no errors. I tried to Clean, Build the project still no luck.

[image: error in eclipse]

```
//Inside Custom Array Adapter
    public class peopleCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements OnClickListener{
        String[] values;
        public peopleCustomArrayAdapter(Context context,String[] values) {
            super(context,R.layout.people_list_row1,values);
            this.values=values;
        }
    }

<!-- people_list_row.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:background="#035633"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textName" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since an adapter (`ArrayAdapter`) class doesn't implicitly import the resources, you have import them manually:

```
import com.example.package.R;
```

You wouldn't need to do that in e.g. a class that extends `Activity`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Instead of `import android.R` I had to use  `import com.example.package_name.R;`. Though I found the solution for this on my own could not update the answer. Anyway thanks for your precious time. :)